# Unable to launch IBM MobileFirst foundation studio 8.0 in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, macos-sierra

OS Version: Mac OS Sierra: 10.12.3

Eclipse Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)

Steps

1. Downloaded the latest Eclipse version.
2. Installed IDE for Java Developers.
3. Installed IBM mobile first foundation studio 8.0 from Eclipse Marketplace. Restarted the Eclipse
4. No mobile first option available in Eclipse.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MobileFirst v8.0 you no longer use Studio to create "projects" to create Hybrid apps, rather you use the Cordova CLI to create a Cordova app, and also use the Cordova CLI to add the MobileFirst SDK (plug-in) to the Cordova app.

The Studio plug-in for Eclipse in v8.0 is used to expose functionality provided by the MobileFirst CLI (register app, open console, and so on...), and so it will work only if you will also have the MobileFirst CLI installed, as well as the THyM plug-in for Eclipse, which makes Eclipse into a dev environment for Cordova apps. See this video : https://youtu.be/yRe2AprnUeg

**Command Line** is the best way to set up the development environment for IBM MobileFirst Foundation 8.0.

> Application development

At the very minimum, the following software is needed:

- NodeJS (requirement for MobileFirst CLI)
- MobileFirst CLI
- Cordova CLI
- IDEs: **Xcode, Android Studio, Visual Studio, Atom.io / Visual Studio Code / WebStorm / IntelliJ / Eclipse / other IDEs**

> Adapter development

- NodeJS (requirement for MobileFirst CLI)
- MobileFirst CLI
- Maven (requires Java)
- IDEs: **IntelliJ / Eclipse / other IDEs**

I suggest that you will take a tour of Setting Up the Development Environment for MobileFirst Foundation 8.0.

See here:

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/using-mobilefirst-cli-in-eclipse/

http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/installation-configuration/development/

http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/installation-configuration/development/cordova/#installing-the-cordova-cli

http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/downloads/#mobilefirst-cli

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Neon is currently not yet supported.  Please try using Juno version instead.