# Suggestion for Mobilefirst mobile application and THyM Mobile application

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-application

I have an application which is support for the platforms Android and iOS. Early i used IBM Woklight - Cordova(6.x).

Then Early Worklight released version 7.0 with name Mobilefirst . So i modifed my application by update mobilefirst version.

Mobilefirst 7.0 not support to run in Anroid studio, So i am using some deprecated methods.

Now Mobilefirst 8.0 ,look like different and its documents seems like should install [THyM](https://www.eclipse.org/thym/) .

If i start using [THyM](https://www.eclipse.org/thym/) , Can possible to use Android studio? And which one is best?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

> **Your Question:** Mobilefirst 7.0 not support to run in Anroid studio, So i am using some deprecated methods.

In MobileFirst 7.x, Gradle is currently not supported in hybrid applications that are generated either in MobileFirst Studio or via the command-line interface (CLI).
If you choose to work with Android Studio, you do not need to install the ADT Eclipse plug-in.

After installing Android Studio, you must configure MobileFirst Studio to use it.
In Eclipse, select  **File > Preferences > MobileFirst** and provide the root location for the Android Studio folder.

> **Your Question:** If i start using THyM , Can possible to use Android studio? And which one is best?

Check this answer: [Unable to launch IBM MobileFirst foundation studio 8.0 in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44644647/unable-to-launch-ibm-mobilefirst-foundation-studio-8-0-in-eclipse/44645577#44645577)