# Eclipse oxygen does not find IBM MobileFirst Studio

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to install IBM MobileFirst Studio. I have downloaded the latest eclipse version (oxygen) for Java EE Developers. Now when I go to "Eclipse Marketplace" and enter "MobileFirst" in search, it does not find the plugin and in the download section of MobileFirst Platform Foundation (https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/downloads/), I can only find the 7.1.0.0 version (under past releases). Nowhere I can find the 8.0 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MobileFirst v8.0 you no longer use Eclipse based MobileFirst Studio to create "projects" to create Hybrid apps, rather you use the Cordova CLI to create a Cordova app, and also use the Cordova CLI to add the MobileFirst SDK (plug-in) to the Cordova app.

Check Here: [Unable to launch IBM MobileFirst foundation studio 8.0 in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44644647/unable-to-launch-ibm-mobilefirst-foundation-studio-8-0-in-eclipse/44645577#44645577)

Comment: Oh Tanks! By the way does this mean I am not bound to use eclipse as IDE but rather I can use any IDE (such as IntelliJ?)